# nginx connection timeout error with python, django and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have setup a django + uwsgi + nginx server according to https://tghw.com/blog/multiple-django-and-flask-sites-with-nginx-and-uwsgi-emperor

The pages work fine when they return quickly. But I have a page that takes about 30 seconds to return and on that page nginx logs show a connection timeout error and a blank page is shown on the browser(Not an error page).

Here are my configuration files:

## nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/consent_architecture;

  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/run/crediwatch_consent.sock;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
  }
}
```

## uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# Variables
base = /var/www/consent_architecture
app = wsgi
# Generic Config
chdir = /var/www/consent_architecture
home = %(base)/venv
plugins = http, python
processes = 5
pythonpath = %(base)
socket = /var/www/run/%n.sock
module = %(app)
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

uwsgi log shows that the call returned in ~25 seconds:

```
[pid: 18713|app: 0|req: 14/25] 127.0.0.1 () {50 vars in 1412 bytes} [Fri Aug 12 18:52:30 2016] POST /consent_server/confirmation => generated 750 bytes in 23503 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 88 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

But the nginx logs shows the following error:

```
2016/08/12 18:53:33 [error] 21203#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /consent_server/confirmation HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/www/run/crediwatch_consent.sock:", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/consent_server/get_details?phone_number=...."
```

The timeout in nginx conf has been set to 5 minutes and uwsgi returns within 30 seconds but nginx doesn't seem to be reading it. Anyone have any clue why this is happening?

Versions:

nginx = 1.4.6, 
uwsgi = 2.0.13.1

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is telling you that your upstream (uWSGI) has timed-out, so adjusting the timeout in Nginx's config won't help.

Try adjusting the internal socket time-out. In your `uswgi.ini`, add:

`socket-timeout = 60`

P.S I see that you've looked at the 14th request out of 25. Are there any other requests that are taking longer that you forgot to include in your log?

Comment: Changing the socket-timeout didn't help. All the requests to that page have the same error. The other pages load fine

Comment: Strange... Sorry it didn't help

Comment: @tarunrs did you figure it out?